# Use Jquery to post to database

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

i get data from an api in json format which i want to access so i can send to database, i have been able to retrieve the data using jquery and here is the code

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td id="javascc"></td><br>

    <td id="javasc"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
{{ HTML::script("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js") }}
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'http://api.XXXX.com/api/v1/info/fuellevel?callback=?',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#javasc').html(data.level);
                    $('#javascc').html(data.name);                
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error occurred not found am sure');
                }
            });
     });

</script>
```

now i want to post to database so i can retrieve it again to use the data got to populate morris line graph data. Please i need help in sending the data to the database, how do i go about it please. I am working on a project using laravel 4.2

Comment: You just add `data : 'whatever',` to the ajax function, and somehow catch it on the server -> [Learn Ajax](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

Comment: sincerely that is where i am lost, i do not know how to achieve that, i do appreciate your help really

Comment: @CE0 in your ajax method add some data like `data: {name1: value1, name2: value2}` .. under `url`